# see bounding boxes of elements in Dreamweaver

Tags: dreamweaver

I would like to see `the edges of all elements` in my html page. That way it is clearly visible what you are doing at any time. Currently I need to click an element to see it's bounding box, which is time consuming if you need to click a lot of elements. Is there an option I need to click to see all the bounding boxes of elements all the time?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. You need to be in `Design mode` to see element boundaries.